I can't make the object bounce
I wanted the circle to bounce when it collided, and I didn't understand what to do next. In short, my object bounces and then falls and doesn't want to bounce a second time. I want you to suggest or help me refine the code, at least so that the object always bounces.
Here is my code:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "SFML works!");

    sf::Vector2f velocityVector = sf::Vector2f(0, 0.5); // velocity vector
    sf::Vector2f massObject = sf::Vector2f(0, 39.0); // the mass of the object

    sf::CircleShape object(10.f, 10.f); // circle(object)
    object.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    object.setPosition(250, 250);

    sf::RectangleShape poll(sf::Vector2f(500.f, 20.f)); // floor
    poll.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    poll.setPosition(0, 482);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        object.move(velocityVector.x, velocityVector.y++); // The rate of fall
        massObject.y--;

        if (object.getPosition().y > 470) // the condition under which the object does not go below
        {
            velocityVector.y = 0.0;
        }

        if (velocityVector.y == 0.0)
            object.move(velocityVector.x, velocityVector.y-- - massObject.y); // rebound

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space)) // return
        {
            velocityVector.y = 0.0;
            massObject.y = 39.0;
            object.setPosition(250, 250);
        }

        //object.setPosition(250, 250);
        //object.setPosition(object.getPosition().x, 480);

        sf::sleep(sf::seconds(0.02));

        window.clear();
        window.draw(object);
        window.draw(poll);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}

I tried to do it in a different way, it seemed to work out, but it wasn't the way I wanted it to. I also tried to try Newton's second law, but also unsuccessfully. Help me solve this problem!

how are you compiling this code?
